# Suppressing "null device" output with R in batch mode

Tags: r, bash, plot, suppress-warnings

I have a number of bash scripts which invoke R scripts for plotting things.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
R --vanilla --slave <<RSCRIPT
cat("Plotting $1 to $2\n")
input <- read.table("$1")
png("$2")
plot(as.numeric(input[1,]))
dev.off()
RSCRIPT
```

The problem is that despite `--slave`, the call to `dev.off()` prints the message `null device 1`.  Once there are a lot of plots being done, or for more complex scripts which plot to a number of files, this gets to be a real hassle.

Is there some way to suppress this message?

Comment: Try: `invisible(dev.off())`

Comment: garbage <- dev.off()

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of the nice things about R is that you can view the source of many functions:

```
> dev.off
function (which = dev.cur()) 
{
    if (which == 1) 
        stop("cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)")
    .Internal(dev.off(as.integer(which)))
    dev.cur()
}
<environment: namespace:grDevices>
```

So it calls `.Internal(dev.off(...))` and then returns dev.cur(), which I suppose would be useful if you have several devices open so you know which one became active. You could use `.Internal(dev.off(as.integer(dev.cur())))` in your script, or even patch `dev.off` to only return the value of `dev.cur()` if it is something else than the null device, and send the patch to the maintainers of R.

Also, `graphics.off()` calls `dev.off()` for all devices and doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 45):

For no good reason I'm aware of, `dev.off()`, unlike device related functions like `png()` returns a value: "the number and name of the new active device."  That value is what's being echoed to stdout.

Suppressing it can thus be achieved by just putting it somewhere, i.e.,

```
garbage <- dev.off()
```

Comment: Simple solution for a simple problem, unlike messing around with implementation details in R. Hence +1 from me.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. The chosen best answer does not work for me. R complains no internal function called dev.off()

Comment: The returned value can also be suppressed with
`invisible(dev.off())`

Answer (score 13):

Ran into the same issue recently and noticed that one more possibility is not mentioned in the answers here:

```
invisible(dev.off())
```

This will hide the output from `dev.off()` and will not create additional variables unlike assigning the output to `garbage` variable: `garbage <- def.off()` would.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use `sink()` and output everything to a log file, so you can check up on whether the plots worked if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) instead which is a) an easier way to write R 'scripts' and b) suppresses output so you get the side effect of dev.off being silent:

```
$ foo.r /tmp/foo.txt /tmp/foo.png
Plotting /tmp/foo.txt to /tmp/foo.png
$ cat /tmp/foo.r
#!/usr/bin/r
cat("Plotting", argv[1], "to", argv[2], "\n")
input <- read.table(argv[1])
png(argv[2])
plot(as.numeric(input[1,]))
dev.off()
$
```

Rscript will probably work too; I tend to prefer littler.

Comment: nice to know about this. but it requires more modifying of the Rscript source. For example, normal variable printing by just giving the variable name will also be silent by default.