# plot panel does not produce plots Rstudio

Tags: plot, panel, rstudio

I am having trouble getting my graphs to appear in the 'plots' window of R studio - once I run the script they appear in a separate R graphics window, separate to R Studio, with the 'plots' tab blank.
when i use

> dev.off()

it gives the error

```
*error in dev.off(): cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)*
```

Even if i ran this command twice the error still there. I tried restart Rstudio- did not work

Comment: `dev.list()` gives NULL

Comment: `print(plot(y,x)`  produce the plot but in pop up window, not inside Rstudio

Answer (score 0):

You might try suppressing the output of dev.off()

Use-

temp <- dev.off()

Also refer similar thread

[Suppressing "null device" output with R in batch mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750703/suppressing-null-device-output-with-r-in-batch-mode)

Comment: no, does not work. plots are still appear in pop up window