# Unable to get plots displayed in Rstudio graphical viewer.

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, rstudio

When I run my code all my graphs (both ggplot2 and plot) are displayed in an external "Quartz 2 [*]" graphical viewer.

I would like them to be displayed in the R studio GUI plot area to I can better save and view my files, along with the previous versions.

Is there anyway to stop this?

I recently updated my version of R, along with the X11 and xQuartz on my mac (also up to date), and I am guessing these updates are behind it.

I have seen many forums explaining how to get rstudio to export to an external viewer (e.g. "quartz()"), but not the other way.

I have looked, but these threads have not helped:

- [ggplot plots in scripts do not display in Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643852/ggplot-plots-in-scripts-do-not-display-in-rstudio)
- [plot panel does not produce plots Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638803/plot-panel-does-not-produce-plots-rstudio)

`dev.off()` even when hidden `hide <- dev.off()` is not working either.

Any help would be great,
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall RStudio?

Comment: what does `options("device")` give

Comment: @user20650 options("device") gives: $device
function (title, width, height, pointsize, family, antialias, 
    type, file = NULL, bg, canvas, dpi) 
{
    if (missing(type) || type %in% c("", "native", "Cocoa")) {
        check <- Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_SCREEN_DEVICE_", "")
        msg <- "screen devices should not be used in examples etc"
        if (identical(check, "stop")) 
            stop(msg, domain = NA)
        else if (identical(check, "warn")) 
            warning(msg, immediate. = TRUE, noBreaks. = TRUE, 
                domain = NA)
    }

Comment: new <- list()
    if (!missing(title)) 
        new$title <- title
    if (!missing(width)) 
        new$width <- width
    if (!missing(height)) 
        new$height <- height
    if (!missing(pointsize)) 
        new$pointsize <- pointsize
    if (!missing(family)) 
        new$family <- family
    if (!missing(antialias)) 
        new$antialias <- antialias
    if (!missing(bg)) 
        new$bg <- bg
    if (!missing(canvas)) 
        new$canvas <- canvas

Comment: if (!missing(type)) 
        new$type <- type
    if (!missing(dpi)) 
        new$dpi <- dpi
    if (!checkIntFormat(new$title)) 
        stop("invalid 'title'")
    if (!is.null(file) && !checkIntFormat(file)) 
        stop("invalid 'file'")
    d <- check.options(new, name.opt = ".quartz.Options", envir = .Quartzenv)
    .External(C_Quartz, d$type, file, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize, 
        d$family, d$antialias, d$title, d$bg, d$canvas, if (is.na(d$dpi)) NULL else d$dpi)
    invisible()
}

Comment: Gosh, that's a lot more output than I expected!! Please can you edit your question with the output - hopefully it helps someone to help you. Have you tried `options(device="RStudioGD")` (dont know if this is sensible as a non-mac user)

Comment: @loki, Thanks! Looks like I forgot to also reinstall Rstudio.. :/

Comment: @user20650 thanks, the problem we me forgetting to reinstall rstudio. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question with the output of `options("device")` instead of copying it peacewise in comments as suggested by @user20650. This might help user OS users. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade R without upgrading RStudio, the graphics engine may not be compatible. To fix the "Quartz 2" popout, upgrade RStudio to a newer version that supports the graphics engine in the version of R you have installed.

I had the same problem, and noticed the following output to the console:

```
Warning message:
R graphics engine version 15 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I forgot to reinstall Rstudio as well.. That sorted my problem.